# How do I include an icon on a Stripes button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coding-style, stripes

I am using Stripes and jQuery along with a generated jQuery UI theme.  I want to embed a `<stripes:form>` in a div, then style the `<stripes:button>` for the submit with one of the icons from the theme.

**This Works:** *(but obviously doesn't tie in to Stripes)*

```
<button id="save" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span>
</button>
```

**This Fails:**

```
<stripes:button name="save" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"></span> 
</stripes:button>
```

The failing one gives me a nicely styled button with the span tag as text.

Any suggestions? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stripes guys always tell people to just use a plain ol' HTML tag when the Stripes tags cause you any sort of grief.  It's not like Stripes does that much for you here, especially if you're not exploiting the mapping from action/field names to properties (message catalog entries).

Comment: I'm a little new to Stripes, does this apply to the <stripes:submit> button as well?

Comment: Wow sorry to leave you hanging. Yes, I would include the "submit" tag. I use the Stripes tags whenever I can, but after a while I got used to using plain HTML when faced with corner cases (and, rarely, bugs and obvious missing features).